# Spring boot embedded tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, maven-tomcat-plugin

```
FATAL: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /manager
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /manager
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:593)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
at 
hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.TomcatAdapter.configure(TomcatAdapter.java:40)
Caused: java.lang.AssertionError
at 
hudson.plugins.deploy.tomcat.TomcatAdapter.configure(TomcatAdapter.java:43)
```

I got an error in Jenkins and looked for why it happend. Jenkins deploy well unless webapp project.
I guess the manager sth in tomcat is blocked cause of security. And I supposed I should manage a tomcat configuration file(tomcat-users.xml). But I can't find the file in embedded-tomcat. Is there anyone who knows what it is happen?

---

Development environment
Spring-boot, tomcat-core8.0.30, jdk-1.8.0_171